# ReportProcessingStatus": "_CANCELLED_" while try to get Orders Report in Amazon MWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-mws

I want to get all the orders details whatever time they are.
So i am trying to generate order report of Amazon mws via Report API and sending the enumeration as "_GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA_" or with other report Enum but as i hit the API RequestReport its gives in response as

```
ReportRequestInfo": {
I20160628-13:14:55.462(5.5)?         "ReportType": "_GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA_",
I20160628-13:14:55.462(5.5)?         "ReportProcessingStatus": "_SUBMITTED_",
I20160628-13:14:55.462(5.5)?         "EndDate": "2016-06-28T07:44:54+00:00",
I20160628-13:14:55.462(5.5)?         "Scheduled": "false",
I20160628-13:14:55.463(5.5)?         "ReportRequestId": "50692016981",
I20160628-13:14:55.463(5.5)?         "SubmittedDate": "2016-06-28T07:44:54+00:00",
I20160628-13:14:55.463(5.5)?         "StartDate": "2016-06-28T07:44:54+00:00"
I20160628-13:14:55.463(5.5)?       }
I20160628-13:14:55.463(5.5)?     },
```

but as i hit the GetReportRequestList API for response the response status show me cancel.

```
 "ReportRequestInfo": [
I20160628-13:15:22.937(5.5)?         {
I20160628-13:15:22.938(5.5)?           "ReportType": "_GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA_",
I20160628-13:15:22.938(5.5)?           "ReportProcessingStatus": "_CANCELLED_",
I20160628-13:15:22.938(5.5)?           "EndDate": "2016-06-28T07:44:54+00:00",
I20160628-13:15:22.938(5.5)?           "Scheduled": "false",
I20160628-13:15:22.939(5.5)?           "ReportRequestId": "50692016981",
I20160628-13:15:22.939(5.5)?           "StartedProcessingDate": "2016-06-28T07:44:58+00:00",
I20160628-13:15:22.939(5.5)?           "SubmittedDate": "2016-06-28T07:44:54+00:00",
I20160628-13:15:22.940(5.5)?           "StartDate": "2016-06-28T07:44:54+00:00",
I20160628-13:15:22.940(5.5)?           "CompletedDate": "2016-06-28T07:45:04+00:00"
I20160628-13:15:22.941(5.5)?         },
I20160628-13:15:22.941(5.5)?         {
I20160628-13:15:22.942(5.5)?           "ReportType": "_GET_CONVERGED_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_",
I20160628-13:15:22.943(5.5)?           "ReportProcessingStatus": "_CANCELLED_",
I20160628-13:15:22.943(5.5)?           "EndDate": "2016-06-28T07:38:44+00:00",
I20160628-13:15:22.943(5.5)?           "Scheduled": "false",
I20160628-13:15:22.943(5.5)?           "ReportRequestId": "50691016981",
I20160628-13:15:22.943(5.5)?           "StartedProcessingDate": "2016-06-28T07:38:49+00:00",
I20160628-13:15:22.944(5.5)?           "SubmittedDate": "2016-06-28T07:38:44+00:00",
I20160628-13:15:22.944(5.5)?           "StartDate": "2016-06-28T07:38:44+00:00",
I20160628-13:15:22.944(5.5)?           "CompletedDate": "2016-06-28T07:38:56+00:00"
I20160628-13:15:22.944(5.5)?         },
I20160628-13:15:22.944(5.5)?         {
I20160628-13:15:22.945(5.5)?           "ReportType": "_GET_CONVERGED_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_",
I20160628-13:15:22.945(5.5)?           "ReportProcessingStatus": "_CANCELLED_",
I20160628-13:15:22.945(5.5)?           "EndDate": "2016-06-28T07:33:09+00:00",
I20160628-13:15:22.945(5.5)?           "Scheduled": "false",
I20160628-13:15:22.945(5.5)?           "ReportRequestId": "50690016981",
I20160628-13:15:22.946(5.5)?           "StartedProcessingDate": "2016-06-28T07:33:14+00:00",
I20160628-13:15:22.946(5.5)?           "SubmittedDate": "2016-06-28T07:33:09+00:00",
I20160628-13:15:22.946(5.5)?           "StartDate": "2016-06-28T07:33:09+00:00",
I20160628-13:15:22.946(5.5)?           "CompletedDate": "2016-06-28T07:33:21+00:00"
I20160628-13:15:22.946(5.5)?         },
```

So as you can see its always say status cancel. I read the documentation that says if you try more than once than the previous one is canclled but as you can see here all the request have status cancel.

Please let me know where i am doing wrong or is there any other way to access the orders report.
Also if anyone know that how we can get all the order details greater than a year than how could one get those.

Any helps would be appriciated
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Parveen are you getting any other error message. and also can you please show your code so that people can tell you if there is any issue.

Comment: From the response I can see the StartDate/EndDate are the same. This means you didn't specify those in your request. With the orders report, I believe you will have to specify those for the report to be generated with orders in the that time-frame.

Comment: @jad Thanks for quick reply as i go through with the doc of amazon mws API they said if you not send  startdate or enddate parameter, they will take the current as default. But i don't understand why they cancel each time.

Comment: @Keyur Thanks for reply i am not getting any other error but each time the status is cancelled.

Comment: @Parveenyadav Yes, it's true that you don't have to specify the dates for the request to be accepted, but that doesn't mean you are guaranteed a successful report. The documentation isn't clear about this. When I first started working with MWS, I had similar issue with FBA Fee Preview Report; my requests were all cancelled until I specified the start/end dates.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @jad Thanks man it works, Actually the issue was that if we don't pass the startdate and enddate to this report than it will takes current date for both for start and end both and there is not any order in between that and that's why Amazon cancel that, as i set the startDate and endDate that will gives me result as expected.Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

MWS [documentation](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html) clearly says that;

> You can only schedule one _GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA_ or _GET_CONVERGED_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_ report at a time. If you have one of these reports scheduled and you schedule a new report, the existing report will be **canceled**.

Check your scheduled reports to verify if you already have this report scheduled.

In addition, reports that aren't real-time reports can also be **canceled** if repeatedly requested, as outlined by Amazon's support tech Jim, on the [MWS forum](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=2497670);

> As you may be aware, many of our reports are not real time and update periodically. In order to keep your report requests running as efficiently as possible and to always provide you with the most updated data, we are now limiting duplicate requests for downloadable reports.
>
> Since our reports update periodically, in most cases, duplicate report requests in quick succession do not display any new information. From now on, when you submit your initial report request, you will be able to generate it once. However, you will not be able to generate a new version of the same report to download again until 30 minutes or 4 hours have passed depending on the report. In the meantime, you can still download the most recently generated report as many times as you want.
>
> NOTE: Near real time reports are capped at once per 30 minutes, while the daily reports are capped at 4 hours.
>
> These new limits are designed to help your report requests run more efficiently and to ensure that we are providing you with the most up-to-date report.

Answer (score -1):

you have to provide dateStartTime atleast in such API. Since in your response I can see the endtime and starttime is same the report is being cancelled as ther is no data for report. Add a valid starttime when you request for such report.